# Android Alert Dialog isShowing property always false

Tags: android, notifications, android-alertdialog

I have the following code, basically I am getting data from a web service every 10 seconds, and displaying what I get each time on an alert dialog and notification. Question is how do I not pop up the alert if the alert has not been close from the previous cycle and is still on the page, so there wont be 2 or more of the same alerts opened at the same time the user has to close.

```
    public class myActivity extends Activity {
public class getActiveAlerts extends Thread {

    public void run() {

        while (true)
        {
        try {
                .... code to get data from web service .....
```

It seems like even when the AlertDialog is present and un-touched, when the next 10 seconds comes, even though the old alert is still there, "alert.isShowing" still shows false and it creates a new alert with the same properties every 10 seconds. ( I would have thought if the alert is opened, alert.isShowing would show true and not create a new alert. Am I doing something wrong here or is there a better way of doing this?

And finally, I don't believe there is a way to detect if a notification is currently active/showing and not clicked-to-closed yet. Is there a standard way of checking if the notification "is showing" when the thread gets called to start again after 10 seconds, so the notification doesn't get created every 10 seconds?

```
                            String root = doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName();
                                //lets set alert title and msg to whatever "root" is for now, root contains the data I get from my web service.

                                myActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(myActivity.this);
                                        alertBuild.setMessage(root)
                                        .setCancelable(false)
                                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        }
                                        }); 
                                        AlertDialog alert = alertBuild.create();
                                        if(alert.isShowing())
                                        {
                                            Log.v("alert", "isShowing==true"); 
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            Log.v("alert", "isShowing==false");
                                            alert.setTitle(root);
                                            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                                            alert.show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                displayNotification(root, root);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }catch (SAXParseException err) {  
                Log.v(" " , err.getMessage ());

                }catch (SAXException e) {
                Exception x = e.getException ();
                ((x == null) ? e : x).printStackTrace ();

                }catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace ();
                }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000); // sleeps for 10 seconds then runs myActivity again
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }// close while loop
    }
}




/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getActiveAlerts thread = new getActiveAlerts();
    thread.start();

}

public void displayNotification(String msg, String desMsg)
{
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, msg + "\n" + desMsg, System.currentTimeMillis());

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, new Intent(this, myActivity.class), 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "new alert", "", contentIntent);

manager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a brand new AlertDialog object every time. Since you just created it, and haven't called show on that particular object, isShowing is false for that particular object. Any previously created dialogs may or may not be showing, but you're not asking those objects.

You can fix this by calling a method on your activity in the runnable with whatever result you want to publish, rather than doing the publishing in the runnable. This would let the activity track a currently showing dialog and not create a new one if one was already visible.

Note that having a reference to your activity in your background thread could potentially be a huge memory leak if your thread's life is longer than that of your activity. Consider storing a weak refence to a listener in your thread, rather than a hard reference to your activity.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are calling alert.isShowing() after creating a new AlertDialog object which will be false until alert.show() is called.